# Sum of a Series

Tags: r

I have been trying to find the sum of a series defined by `Σ(1+r(i))^1:n` in R where `i` and `n` is in `(1:N)`.  Both `i` and `n` are of the same length. The solution needs to be two functions, where `function 1` calculates the expression `(1+r)^n` and the second `function 2` recursively calls `function 1` to calculate the summation. I am struggling to create a way to call `function 1` within `function 2` and having it calculate the values recursively.

Example:

```
Rates   Tenor   Printrest  
1.20%   1   1.012  
1.35%   2   1.02718225  
1.90%   3   1.058089859  
2.01%   4   1.082856706  
1.80%   5   1.093298847  
1.70%   6   1.106434521
```

Answer  6.379862183

Answer (score 1):

I think `within` and `cumsum` functions solve your problem.
The last row in `comp.acc` column has what you want.

```
> data.txt <- 'Rates   Tenor   Printrest  
+ 1.20   1   1.012  
+ 1.35   2   1.02718225  
+ 1.90   3   1.058089859  
+ 2.01   4   1.082856706  
+ 1.80   5   1.093298847  
+ 1.70   6   1.106434521'
> 
> df <- read.table(text=data.txt, header = TRUE)
> 
> within(df, {
+   comp <- (1 + Rates/100)^(Tenor)
+   comp.acc <- cumsum(comp)
+ })
  Rates Tenor Printrest comp.acc     comp
1  1.20     1  1.012000 1.012000 1.012000
2  1.35     2  1.027182 2.039182 1.027182
3  1.90     3  1.058090 3.097272 1.058090
4  2.01     4  1.082857 4.180129 1.082857
5  1.80     5  1.093299 5.273428 1.093299
6  1.70     6  1.106435 6.379862 1.106435
```

Comment: This is insightful and I will try if I can use this for what I intend to do. However, I was looking at a recursive and nested function. The above data was used as an example. My actual formula is a little more complicated and `N` is dynamically generated and recursively applied.   I am trying to `bootstrap (finance)` a zero coupon yield curve from fed data.